# Liouville's Theorem Inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

So i have the following Problem/Question

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ and not constant. Show, that for every $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and
all $\varepsilon > 0$  there exists a $z \in \mathbb{C}$, so
$|f(z) − z_0| \leq \varepsilon$.

so i am 99% sure that we are expected to solve this using Liouville's Theorem since the first part of the exercise (this is part b)) asks us to state his theorem plus the ''not constant'' part makes you instantly think of it

so far i have had the following thoughts/attempts

1)my first thought was to let $g(z)$ be the difference of the to be proven inequality and somehow show that it is bounded hence constant and then show that the modulus of the difference of $f-z_0$ is less than $0$ so less than $\varepsilon$ and hence the inequality is proven but given that we only know $g$ would be holomorphic i don't think i can do that-side thought was to assume it isn't true and find a contradiction but i haven't been able to do that

2. then i thought about maybe splitting $f$ into $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and using the infinite differentiability of the function(for instance maybe $f'$ is constant so then $f$ is a most linear and so a polynomial of degree $1$ and by generalised Liouville we could maybe get somewhere) but that didn't pan out either

3)lastly i thought about maybe taylor expanding $f$ around $z_0$ but we haven't done anything even remotely similar as a solution and our exam is on wednesday so i doubt this is it

also just to be clear this is from a set of 9 exercises that we were given that will be similar to the ones in our exam-so not a HW problem or anything like that

Comment: Can you edit your post to use MathJax? You can find a tutorial on this site.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this is just Casorati Weierstrass applied at infinity

Comment: @AShrike Not really. It's just Liouville's.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose on the contrary that there exist $z_0\in \mathbb C$ and an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $z, |f(z)-z_0|\gt \epsilon_0$. Define $g(z)= \frac 1{f(z)- z_0}$. Use Liouville's on $g$.

Comment: ok i have 2 problems with your suggestion
1)g is not entire since f(z) could at some point be equal to z_0 so i am not sure we can use Liouville
2) even if we can, i show that g is constant and equal to let's say c, then f(z)-z_0 is equal to 1/c
my inequality needs to hold for all ε>0 and obviously some ε will be bigger than 1/c no matter what c is unless c is negative but i don't think i can show that
am i missing something?

Comment: @SpyrosMavrokefalidis $f(z)$ could not be $z_0$ because $|f(z)-z_0|>\epsilon$ always

Comment: @SpyrosMavrokefalidis 1) If $|f(z) - z_0| > 0$ then $f(z) \neq z_0$. 2) What is done here is a proof by contradiction, where finding a contradiction will automatically mean that the negation of the contradictory statement is valid, which here is the original claim. The contradiction here is that $f$ is proven to be constant, when it's assumed not to be constant.

Comment: yeah ok it makes sense now i forgot about the implicit assumption that f is not constant from the description and just focused on g
thank you